# How do I enable Java in Microsoft Edge web browser?

Tags: java, microsoft-edge

My corporate web application is using Java applet to access users file system. There is no way for us to replace it with anything else for now.

How do I enable Java in Microsoft Edge?

Comment: probably can't, since edge dropped support for plugins.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As other folks have mentioned, Java, ActiveX, Silverlight, Browser Helper Objects (BHOs) and other plugins are not supported in Microsoft Edge. Most modern browsers are moving away from plugins and toward standard HTML5 controls and technologies.

If you must continue to use the Java plugin in a corporate web app, consider adding the site to an [Enterprise Mode site list](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270205.aspx). This will automatically prompt the user to open in IE.

Comment: @ITHitWebDAV What code do you have that suggests ActiveX is supported in Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Also of note, Microsoft ending support for IE11 on 15 June 2022: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549

Answer (score 14):

You cannot open Java Applets (nor any other [NPAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) plugin) in Microsoft Edge - they aren't supported and won't be added in the future.

Further you should be aware that in the next release of Google Chrome (v45 - due September 2015) [NPAPI plugins will also no longer be supported](https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation).

### Work-arounds

There are a couple of things that you can do:

**Use Internet Explorer 11**
You will find that in Windows 10 you will already have Internet Explorer 11 installed. IE 11 continues to support NPAPI (incl Java Applets). 
IE11 is squirrelled away (`c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe`). Just pin this exe to your task bar for easy access.

**Use FireFox**
You can also install and use a Firefox 32-bit Extended Support Release in Win10. [Firefox have disabled NPAPI by default, but this can be overridden](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/firefox_java.xml). This will [only be supported until early 2018](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Problems-with-add-ons-plugins-or/Why-do-Java-Silverlight-Adobe-Acrobat-and-other-plugins-no/ta-p/31069).

Comment: IE11 does not support NPAPI, nor has any recent version of IE. IE supports ActiveX plugins, which are a completely different technology.

Comment: @smorgan according to https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml "The Java plug-in for web browsers relies on the cross platform plugin architecture NPAPI...". Java Plugins _do_ work in IE11. To help subsequent readers could you supply some additional information regarding your findings please?

Comment: Yes, it says that on a page *about Chrome* (note "chrome" in the URL). You can trivially find lots of pages that discuss this. For instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI#Browser_support, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/overview-136653.html (look for "Internet EXplorer"), http://colonelpanic.net/2010/08/browser-plugins-vs-extensions-the-difference/

Comment: Note that plugins are now going away in Firefox as well: https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/10/08/npapi-plugins-in-firefox/

Comment: @phk that is correct - what that page doesn't reveal is that there is an *Extended Support Release* of Firefox that will continue to support plugins for a few months for those that need more time to transition: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/

Answer (score 6):

Edge has dropped all support for plugins. This means that Java, ActiveX, Silverlight, and other plugins are no longer supported. For this reason Microsoft has included Internet Explorer 11, which does support these plugins, with non-mobile versions of Windows 10. If you are running Windows 10 and need plugin support Edge is not an option, but IE 11 is.

Answer (score 3):

About this, java declares that on Windows 10, Edge browser does not support plugins, so it will NOT run java.
(see https://www.java.com/it/download/win10.jsp --> only visible with edge in win10)
It also reports a notice: java is not officially supported yet in Windows 10.
(see https://www.java.com/it/download/faq/win10_faq.xml)

Answer (score 1):

IE11 do accept Java according to the link below :
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/install-java#ie=ie-11

And firefox also intended to remove NPAPI by the end of 2016 according to :
https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/10/08/npapi-plugins-in-firefox/

Answer (score 0):

That Java Applets are not working in modern browsers is known but there is a quick workaround which is activate the Microsoft Compatibility Mode. This mode can be activated in your Edge browser and you can select to open  the pages on the IE compatibility mode, and in this fashion the ActivX and Java and so works as in IE11.
M Edge in IE mode supports the following Internet Explorer functionality:

- All document modes and enterprise modes
- ActiveX controls (such as Java or Silverlight)

As refs:

- https://query.prod.cms.rt.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWEHMs

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing well.

You can download add edge extension on MS edge browser that will allow you to run java applet.

You can try the extension called : **CheerpJ Applet Runner**