# Unable to open applet in any of the browser

Tags: java, html, applet

I am trying to embed applet into an html page and view it in a browser, but i am unable to view it in any of the browsers. (Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Internet Explorer are the browsers i have checked, and also i have enabled the java applets in all of the above.)

Below is my code for applet.java file.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
 import java.awt.Graphics;

 public class MyApplet extends Applet {
     @Override
     public void paint(Graphics g) {
         g.drawString("Hello applet!", 50, 25);
     }
 }
```

Below is the code for html file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>First Applet</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is my first applet.</p>
        <embed code="MyApplet.class" 
            codebase="."
            type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.8">
            <noembed>
                No Java Support.
            </noembed>
        </embed>
</body></html>
```

> .class file, .java file and .html files are all in the same folder.

Comment: Are Java applets still supported by modern browsers?

Comment: [Oracle reveals Java Applet API deprecation plan](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/08/24/oracle_reveals_java_applet_api_deprecation_plan/), [Why applets in JDK 9 are deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535112/why-applets-in-jdk-9-are-deprecated), [The clock is ticking: The Java browser plugin will be deprecated soon](https://jaxenter.com/clock-ticking-java-browser-plugin-will-deprecated-soon-131546.html)

Comment: [Oracle's finally killing its terrible Java browser plugin](https://www.theverge.com/2016/1/28/10858250/oracle-java-plugin-deprecation-jdk-9), [JDK 9 and the Java Plugin](https://java.com/en/download/faq/jdk9_plugin.xml)

Comment: The fact is, like Flash, Java Applets are dead technology, which most browsers are not actively disabling or refusing to support ... and to be honest, good riddance

Comment: @MadProgrammer "good riddance" Hear, hear. Though it was the security holes continually reintroduced into plug-ins that likely caused the browser makes to decide to remove support, a rich client Java applet in a thin client web page was always a quirky mix that barely worked.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Every meeting I was ever in - manager/client "I have a great idea, lets make it an applet!"; me - Hands in resignation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern Browsers does not support java applets; as per below post on official Java website:

> https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml
>
> The Java Plugin for web browsers relies on the cross-platform plugin architecture NPAPI, which had been supported by all major web browsers for over a decade. Google's Chrome version 45 and above have dropped support for NPAPI, and therefore Java Plugin do not work on these browsers anymore.

Also, for edge, [this stackover flow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816839/how-do-i-enable-java-in-microsoft-edge-web-browser) indicates the same...