# Can not run java runtime on Microsoft Edge

Tags: java, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have app server built with Oracle java. It run ok in win 10 and win 7 through internet explorer with java runtime. But i dont know how to run it through Microsoft edge, it always show blank screen.
Sorry for bad english.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable Java in Microsoft Edge web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816839/how-do-i-enable-java-in-microsoft-edge-web-browser) Note also that Java applets are no longer supported in other modern browsers including Firefox and Chrome without using an older version or installing a special plugin.

Comment: thanks, but it not work

Comment: Yes Java Applets will not work they are an old technology. If you do not have a Java Applet, then please edit your question to add more information about what your project is, then we can give more answers.